# Scroll Text in Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, autocomplete

I found the following fiddle which prevents any word wrap in autocomplete suggestions and only displays them in one line:

http://jsfiddle.net/DwpZp/8/

```js
$("#ac").autocomplete({
  source: [
    "someveryve rylonglongword",
    "someveryverylong longwordsomeveryverylonglongword"
  ]
});
```

```css
.ui-menu-item a {
  max-width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <input type="text" id="ac" />
</div>
```

Is there any way to **animate the autocomplete suggestions that overflow the max-width and to make them autoscroll from left to right on mouse hover?** Please see the following snippet with the example of the autoscroll on hover animation I would like to implement:

```css
.labelContainer {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding : 5px;
}

.labelContainer span {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: 1s;
}

.labelContainer:first-of-type:hover span {
  width: auto;
  transform: translateX(calc(200px - 100%));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="labelContainer">
      <span>The long text should scroll when user hovers on it.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="labelContainer">
      <span>Should Not Scroll</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```js
$("#ac").autocomplete({
  source: [
    "someveryve rylonglongword",
    "someveryverylong longwordsomeveryverylonglongword"
  ]
});
```

```css
.ui-menu-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-menu-item a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ui-menu-item:hover a {
  width: auto;
  transform: translateX(calc(200px - 100%));
}

.ui-widget-content a.ui-state-focus {
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <input type="text" id="ac" />
</div>
```

Comment: Dear @yunzen, thank you very much for your reply. Your code does work with long autocomplete suggestions but unfortunately it also scrolls short items out of view, even though they don't overflow the width. Also, I've realized that hovering over items is not the best way to trigger the animation and I would like to use something like `.ui-state-active` class for that. That way the scrolling will also work If I use the arrow keys to select the suggestion. Could you please help me out with these problems?

Comment: I've managed to change the way the animation is triggered by replacing this part of  your code `.ui-menu-item:hover a { width: auto; transform: translateX(calc(200px - 100%));
}` with this `.ui-menu-item a.ui-state-focus { width: auto; transform: translateX(calc(200px - 100%));}`. Still can't deal with short items being scrolled, though.

Comment: Dear @yunzen, I've also just noticed that in your code there's no `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property which was in the original fiddle and thus it becomes difficult to tell which autocomplete suggestion is actually overflown.